# Why is Spring @Autowired ApplicationContext null in integration test?

Tags: java, spring

I'm still new to Spring and have looked at similar questions on stack but couldn't identify an answer from what I've read.

I'm receiving an NPE when I call my applicationContext variable, which means the bean must not have been created or injected correctly. Here is the relevant portion of my program.

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfig.class)
public class SampleIT {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Test
    public void sampleMethod() throws Exception {

        //NPE below
        String[] allBeanNames = applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();

        //more logic
```

I'm trying to get the ApplicationContext instance to debug why other beans are null from my config, so this all must be because of a basic flaw in my understanding of how ApplicationContext is setup and beans from it are injected. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using JUnit 4 or 5?

Comment: Using Junit 4.12 @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to add the following annotation to your class `SampleIT`:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
```

Comment: This is no longer necessary in JUnit 5, but if the OP is using JUnit 4, it may be the answer.

Comment: Ok this seems to fix the null injections problem! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question now. Importing `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` instead of `org.junit.Test` will cause Junit5 to be used. This will allow Junit to work with Spring without the `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotation. There are still remnants of Junit4 left in the codebase I'm working in, so this is a quick fix before completely moving to Junit 5.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Junit in version 4, You have to use @RunWith(SpringRunner.class),
If you are using Junit version 5, You have to use @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class).

Additionally if you are using Mockito You can use @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) etc.

I highly recommend read documentation about `@SpringBootTest` annotation in this link
[@SpringBootTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html)

Comment: The part about Junit 5 is not true. ```@SpringBootTest``` already includes ```@ExtendWith(value=org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.class)```